# Angular JS populate Select Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**I have the following array**

```
$scope.profissionais = {}
```

**I have the following array**

```
[{"usuario":"14","username":"Renê Lima"},{"usuario":"16","username":"Thaís"}]
```

**I'm trying populates it with the following code**

```
<option ng:repeat="prof in profissionais" value="{{prof.usuario}}">
    {{prof.username}}
</option>
```

**However it did not work but also not give any error, akguem help me? TKS**

Comment: Its `ng-repeat`. also read the docs on ngOptions its the way angular recommends. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng:repeat to ng-repeat  :)

```
$scope.singleSelect = null
$scope.profissionais = [
  {usuario:"14",username:"Renê Lima"},    
  {usuario:"16",username:"Thaís"}
];

<select ng-model="singleSelect">
  <option ng-repeat="prof in profissionais" ng-value="prof.usuario">{{prof.username}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: prof in profissionais, Duplicate key: string:i, Duplicate value: i

Comment: The error message is telling you that key of your array is duplicated. Can you show me result of $log.log($scope.profissionais)? Also I just updated the answer. Try with this.

Comment: complete array... `[{"usuario":"14","username":"Renê Lima","profissao":"2","tratamento":"Dr.","descricao":"Médico"},{"usuario":"16","username":"Thaís","profissao":"2","tratamento":"Dra.","descricao":"Médico"}]`

Comment: change value to ng-value and remove bracket of "prof.usuario"

Comment: I just updated the answer, you should remove quotation of each key